# Example of completion in number theory

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, big-list

In Algebraic Number Theory we have a standard setting: let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its fraction field, $L/K$ be a finite separable extension and $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

Since $B$ is also a Dedekind domain, one of the basic problems is: given a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, find the factorization of $\mathfrak{p}B$ into prime ideals. A lot of the theory is based on simplifying this problem. For example, if $L/K$ is Galois, then Hilbert's ramification theory shows that this problem becomes a lot easier.

I think I understood the basic results of completion (for example, both the ramification index and the residual degree stay the same upon completion, and we always have that $B=A[\alpha]$ after completing) but I have yet to see an example of this being used in a concrete problem. I searched on the internet and on some books and found absolutely nothing.

I would appreciate seeing an example of the use of completion to solve a concrete problem (perhaps the basic problem described above) in number theory.

Comment: The obvious example that comes to mind is using the combinatorial data of the Newton polygon to determine the ramification.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I actually never studied the Newton polygon. Do you have a concrete example of its use?

Comment: Yes, let $p$ be prime, and consider $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. Then the minimal polynomial is $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}+ ... + 1$. If we substitute $(x + 1)$ we have a new polynomial $x^{p-1} + px \cdot(stuff) + p$. Then the Newton polygon at the prime $p$ has one segment with slope $1/(p-1)$. Thus the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p) / \mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified (with uniformiser $\zeta_p - 1$), and hence the prime ideal $(p)$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey The slope in this case is $-1/(p-1)$ isn't it? Other than that, I don't really understand how you concluded that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified nor how you concluded that $(p)$ is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.

Comment: No, the Newton polygon will have positive slope if the coefficents are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It is a result that the slope of the segments of the Newton polygon are the valuation of the roots. If $\alpha$ is a root and $K = \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ then $v_K(\alpha) = e_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p} v_p (\alpha) = e_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p} / (p-1)$ but the LHS is in $\mathbb{Z}$ and the $e$ is $\leq p - 1$ so equality must hold and we conclude that the extension is totally ramified.